# Apache Velocity #parse a file if it exists

Tags: velocity

I'm working with Apache Velocity and I'm trying to include another `.vtl` file. The problem is that this file is not nessacery to have.

```
#parse("${PROJECT_NAME}-variables.vtl")
```

I was hoping I could something like this:

```
#if(#parse("${PROJECT_NAME}-variables.vtl"))
dostuff
#else
dontdostuff
#end
```

Can I write an if statement to check if the file exists? Or is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is check that the file exists in Java and set a boolean for my if statement to check.